# Changing Value of a Column to Dollar Amount and Multiplying by $100,000

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with this dataset https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1z8xKwVCWPjSSr3iLwyDXKb71A2fRUEK_ and the column Price has to be multiplied by $100,000 to get the actual home value.

I want to know how to create a new column by multiplying the 100,000 and also putting it in dollar value if possible?

I am not sure if what I did is the best way to do so!

```
housing <- read_csv("housing_new.csv")

new_housing <- housing %>%
  mutate(price * 100000)
```

Comment: Try changing the last line to `mutate(price = scales::dollar(100000 * price))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a new column as below:

```
housing$new_price <- housing$price*100000
```

For adding $ in front, you can use the paste function:

```
housing$new_price <- paste('$', housing$price*100000, sep=' ')
```

If you want to use mutate:

```
housing <- housing %>% mutate(new_price = paste('$', price*100000, sep=' '))
```